# How to run one function only after another, at pushbutton using PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt

I've read multiple posts on this and couldn't fix my code.

I'm running a GUI (using PyQt5) that runs a function (`Extraction()`) from another script (`file_py`). What I want to do is the script to display a Green Led picture (.png) at start, and then when pushbutton is clicked, before running `Extraction()`, the GUI would display a Red Led picture.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import file_py as my_script

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.trigger_status_icon)
        
        self.LED_Green = QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Desktop/green-led-on.png")
        self.LED_Red = QtGui.QPixmap("C:/Desktop/red-led-on.png")
        self.labelStatus = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.labelStatus.setPixmap(self.LED_Green) #starting GUI with a Green Led picture
        self.labelStatus.setScaledContents(True)


    def trigger_status_icon(self):
        self.labelStatus.setPixmap(self.LED_Red)
        return self.run_Script()

    def run_Script(self):
        my_script.Extraction()
```

But what I'm getting with this code is the following: At the start of the GUI a Green Led picture is displayed. After pushbutton is clicked the function `Extraction()` runs, and only after it finishes the Led Red picture appears.

What can I do so that the Led Red picture is run before the function `Extraction()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding `QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()` after assigning the picture it will refresh the QtWidget.

```
def trigger_status_icon(self):
    self.labelStatus.setPixmap(self.LED_Red)
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    return self.run_Script()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just a note --  the `processEvents()` may need to be called periodically _inside_ the `run_Script` method to keep the UI from freezing.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a change in UI followed by some "lengthy" operation you can explicitly refresh the UI by using the `QWidget.update` method:

```
def trigger_status_icon(self):
        self.labelStatus.setPixmap(self.LED_Red)
        self.update()
        return self.run_Script()
```

Comment: If I add that `self.update()` I get the error message : " 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'update'". If call explicitly the Widget  `self.labelStatus.update()` I continue with my problem, that is, it only changes the picture after it runs the script

Comment: Yes, this was a wrong answer. The correct answer is to let the application process events as was stated by @eduardo2111

Comment: @eduardo2111 if you get that error, it's because you're using an edited pyuic file. Exiting those files is always discouraged and is considered bad practice for lots of reasons, including the fact that inexperienced users use them in the wrong way, expecting that their classes behave like a QWidget while they're not (which is exactly your case).

Comment: @musicamante why is it bad practice to edit a pyuic? I thought it was a shortcut to get better written GUIs.

Comment: @eduardo2111 There are a lot of reasons, like: whenever you need to do some changes to the UI, merging the changes is a mess and often results in forgotten or misplaced parts of code; complex UIs make the whole code extremely extended, and separating the logic from the ui is anyway a better choice as it makes the code cleaner; the form class (Ui_MainWindow) is a basic python object, so you cannot override the actual widget's functions and you would need to subclass the base widget anyway; since the form class is *not* a QWidget, it cannot be used as a Qt *parent*.

Comment: @eduardo2111 Editing those files is not a "shortcut" for better written GUIs: 99% of the times is something that sooner or later will lead to some problems that can be avoided by properly using them as explained in [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html): by importing. That allows proper implementation, as in this way the *widget* class can be extended as required without unnecessarily complicating things and worrying about the "ui code". Note that pyqt also allows direct load of the ui file with the `uic` module: `uic.loadUi('file.ui', self)`.